# act warning when testing component with Material UI Tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

This is a follow up on https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15726#issuecomment-507293766

I have a component `Registration` which has a button, that is by default is disabled (controlled by clicking a checkbox, accepting terms and conditions), and shows a tooltip message if hovered over,  to accept terms and conditions. Below is the result of the test, and the test itself.

```js
√ without consent, cannot go further (190ms)

  console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
    Warning: An update to ForwardRef(Popper) inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).        
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
        act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });
    /* assert on the output */
        This ensures that you're testing the behavior the user would see in the browser. Learn more at ...
        in ForwardRef(Popper) (created by Tooltip)
        in Tooltip (created by WithStyles(Tooltip))
      ....
```

My test (using `@testing-library/react`):

```js
jest.useFakeTimers()
it('without consent, cannot go further', () => {
  const {getByText} = render(<Registration/>)
  const loginButton = getByText(/Log in/)
  act(() => {
    fireEvent.mouseEnter(loginButton)
    jest.runAllTimers()
  })
  expect(getByText(/Please accept our terms and conditions/)).toBeInTheDocument()
})
```

I added fake timers as suggested on the GitHub issue, but it did not help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't worry about the act warning. It's going to get fixed in the next version of React. See [here](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/281) for more info.

Comment: Confirmed, I just checked, it goes away, in react@16.9.0-alpha.0 don't even need the timers!

Answer (score 5):

I just update my project from react "16.8.6" to "16.9.0" and I still have the same error on the console...

Update:
To fix some of the errors I had to add `act(() => { functionThatUpdateState(); })`

For other errors like when using Material Ui Tooltip I had to do:

```js
beforeEach(() => {
   jest.useFakeTimers();
})

it("should do something", () => {
  act(() => {
     const { getByText } = render(<MyComponent />);
     jest.runAllTimers();
     expect(getByText("hey")).toBeDefined();
  })
});
```